# In Angular, why would I use jasmine.createSpyObj instead of simply passing an object to the provider's useValue?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm just getting started with Angular and unit testing and I'd like to test a `Component` that has a dependency on `ActivatedRoute`.

My `Component` has an `ngOnInit` method that looks like so:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    //get data using the id
}
```

So in my test's `beforeEach` function I'm trying to set up the testbed like so (note, this was *before* I got my test to work):

```
    let mockRoute;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        //this example didn't work, the test failed trying to reach the .get('id') call
        mockRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockRoute', ['snapshot.paramMap.get']);
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, mockRoute }],
            declarations: [ MyComponentToTest ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    });
```

I was using `jasmine.createSpyObj` because I was following a pluralsight example, but after the example above didn't work, I ended up finding this on the interwebs:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    //this example worked
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
        {
            provide: ActivatedRoute,
            useValue: {
                snapshot: {
                    paramMap: {
                        get: () => 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }],
        declarations: [ MyComponentToTest ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
});
```

I see plenty of documentation (and the pluralsight video) on using `jasmine.createSpyObj` to create mocks but in my case it did not work as well as `useValue`, so then does anybody know why anyone would use the `jasmine.createSpyObj` instead? does it exist for a very specific use that `useValue` can't work with?

Comment: Jasmine's Spy objects gives you a lot of nice things like keeping track of how often the method has been called etc, which can be used in your test without setting up logic for it. You can read about it here https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies . The Angular documentation recommends it. https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#services-with-dependencies

Comment: You should probably create a question asking about why your spy doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I use `jasmine.createSpyObj` to mock `public` methods of a class. It doesn't do a good job in mocking `public` instance variables.

```
// the first string argument in jasmine.createSpyObj is for debugging purposes, basically it will say
// publicNameForDebugging.names was not called
// the second argument is an array of strings of public methods you would like to mock
mock = jasmine.createSpyObj('publicNameForDebugging', ['names', 'of', 'public', 'methods'])
```

For your case, for the activated route you have no public methods to mock but the following should work using createSpyObj:

```
    let mockRoute;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        //this example didn't work, the test failed trying to reach the .get('id') call
        // have to put 'anything' because you might get an error if the second argument
        // is an empty array
        mockRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockRoute', ['anything']);
        // mock the instance variables and attach them to the spyObj just created
        mockRoute.snapshot = {};
        mockRoute.snapshot.paramMap = {};
        mockRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get = () => 1;
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, mockRoute }],
            declarations: [ MyComponentToTest ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    });
```